# PHP tabla con ciclos

Tags: php

Tengo que crear una tabla usando ciclos para una pagina web con php, así es la tabla:

[image: tabla]

De código llevo esto:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
          $i=5;
            for(){
            } 
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que intentas hacer, es una matriz. Para ello mínimo necesitas hacer 2 ciclos, uno dentro del otro, es decir, primero debes de crear las filas y después las columnas.

te dejo un ejemplo, de como sería esto.

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=$filas; $i++){


    for($x=1; $x<=$columnas; $x++){
        echo "operación $x|";
    }
    echo "<br>\n";
}
?>
```

el cual nos da este resultado:
[image: Matriz]

ahora bien, sabiendo como funciona, solo sería que se hagan las operaciones

```
<?php

$columnas = 10;
$filas = 10;

echo "<table border='1'>";

for($i=1; $i<=$filas; $i++){

    echo "<tr>";

    for($x=1; $x<=$columnas; $x++){
        echo "<td>".$i."*".$x." = ".($i * $x)."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Y así quedaría tu tabla.

[image: tabla multiplicar, matriz]

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS :) de verdad que sos un crack, tenía una idea muy vaga de como hacerlo pero me funciono y le entendí

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo con:

- Dos ciclos `foreach` uno para las filas y otro para las columnas, usando `range` para indicar desde que punto inicia y en que punto termine cada ciclo
- Para poder obtener el número que multiplicaremos por 1, 2 y 3 será el de la variable `$columnas` que lo asignamos a una nueva variable y a esa le sumamos 4; para que de este modo el primer recorrido haga *5*1, 5*2.......*
- A la nueva variable `$columna` la multiplicamos por `$filas` y con esto generamos la leyenda de la multiplicación `número * x = ?` por cada una de las 3 filas
- La misma multiplicación anterior la generamos para obtener el resultado de dicha operación, este será el resultado que aparezca a lado derecho de cada leyenda

Código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>uno</th>
            <th>ds</th>
            <th>tres</th>
        </tr>
            <?php
                foreach(range(1, 3) as $columnas) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        foreach(range(1, 3) as $filas) {
                            $columna = $columnas + 4;
                            echo "<td>"."$columna * $filas = ".$columna * $filas."</td>";
                        }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Obteniendo este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]